# MySQL Stored Procedure: Unknown column 'Table_Name' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am currently attempting to create my first Stored Procedure with:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE  `GetNumRows` ( IN tab_name VARCHAR( 40 ) )
BEGIN 
SET @t1 = CONCAT(  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', tab_name) ;

PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1 ;

EXECUTE stmt3;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

END$$
```

And calling it with this:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->query("CALL GetNumRows($this->tableName)");
if($query == false)
{
    die("mySQLi Error: ".$this->mysqli->error);
}
```

Obviously, I don't even get past this, I get this on die:

```
mySQLi Error: Unknown column 'gps_location' in 'field list'
```

How can I modify my Stored Procedure in order to allow for a Table Name to be passed in and be able to get the Number of Rows.

Answer (score 1):

Create the SP like this. It is most likley not looking in the right database.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE  `GetNumRows` (IN database_name VARCHAR(50), 
IN tab_name VARCHAR(40) )
BEGIN 

SET @t1 = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ',database_name,'.', tab_name,';');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1 ;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

END$$
```

And make sure the CALL parameter is wrapped with `'`. Im not sure how to include ' with php but im sure you know it :)

```
CALL GetNumRows('$this->tableName')
```

EDIT

Ive now changed so that database name is also passed as a parameter.

Comment: I can create the SP just fine. And run it.

Comment: You get this when you create the SP? Or when you call it?

Comment: Try both, `CALL GetNumRows('$this->tableName')` and `CALL GetNumRows($this->tableName)`. Maybe this `$this->tableName` allready has ' wrapped around it?

Comment: Ok great! Please elaborate, im not sure what you mean!

Comment: WEll, you could use that as a parameter also. If you dont include the name of the database, mysql will look in the current session database, giving a risk for error.

Comment: Actually, my original MySQL looks just fine! Simply have to call with quotes: `CALL GetNumRows('gps_location')` If you would like to edit, since you helped me get to that answer, you may edit to that solution.

Comment: Also, delete the other comments please, as they would not help somebody trying to search for the answer.

Comment: You should include the `databasename` before the `tablename`. That is the best practice to have. This ensures that the correct database is used. This is such a simple thing, i dont think the comments will confuse anyone.

Comment: For PHP, you always declare the Database you are using regaurdless, IE: `$this->mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['dbname']);`